# How to break apart a URI in WP7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, query-string

Is there a method for accesing Query parameters in the WebBrowser control or do we have to manually break apart the string? For example:

```
http://www.mysite.com?paramter=12345
```

I simply need to access the value of parameter. I know when working with xaml pages we have the have the QueryString property. Is there something similar for working with web pages?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext.querystring(v=vs.92).aspx

This seems to have QueryContext property in Windows Phone as well.

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat Yes I saw that to, but if you notice this is for XAML pages and the navigation between them. I actually need a solution for web pages in the browser control.

Comment: if your page is asp.net page then you could use HttpRequest.QueryString but you probably already know that. In case of static page you could probably use some jquery extension. Even custom parsing doesn't seem to be a bad idea if nothing else is available

Comment: Yeah It's looking like custom parsing is the only solution. Still kind of surprising there isn't a method for this sort of thing.

Comment: @loyalpenguin Still custom but at least a extension method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't remember where I got this, possibly SO.

```
 public static class UriExtensions
    {
        private static readonly Regex QueryStringRegex = new Regex(@"[\?&](?<name>[^&=]+)=(?<value>[^&=]+)");

        public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ParseQueryString(this Uri uri)
        {
            if (uri == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("uri");

            var matches = QueryStringRegex.Matches(uri.OriginalString);
            for (var i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
            {
                var match = matches[i];
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(match.Groups["name"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe it should be yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(match.Groups["name"].Value), HttpUtility.UrlDecode(match.Groups["value"].Value));

Comment: `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` won't let you check for a specific key. You will want at least an `ICollection` or `IDictionary`.

Answer (score 2):

Some important optimizations from other answers:

- handling a *#* in the Uri
- handling possible missing value like *&name=* in the Uri
- not forgetting `Uri.UnescapeDataString`
- returning a `Dictionary` instead of a `IEnumerable` so one can find a desired parameter easily
- explaining that `Uri.Query` is unreliable on WP7
- comparing speed for best solution

With Regex (**slower than Split**):

```
static readonly Regex QueryStringRegex1 = new Regex(@"^[^#]*\?([^#]*)");
static readonly Regex QueryStringRegex2 = new Regex(@"(?<name>[^&=]+)=(?<value>[^&=]*)");
public static Dictionary<string, string> QueryDictionary(this Uri uri)
{
    return QueryStringRegex1.Match(uri.ToString())// between ? and #
        .Groups
        .Cast<Group>()
        .Select(a => QueryStringRegex2.Matches(a.Value)// between ? and &
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(b => b.Groups)
            .ToDictionary(b => Uri.UnescapeDataString(b["name"].Value), b => Uri.UnescapeDataString(b["value"].Value)))
        .ElementAtOrDefault(1)
        ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

With Split (**faster than Regex**, recommended solution):

```
static readonly char[] QueryStringSeparator1 = "#".ToCharArray();
static readonly char[] QueryStringSeparator2 = "?".ToCharArray();
static readonly char[] QueryStringSeparator3 = "&".ToCharArray();
static readonly char[] QueryStringSeparator4 = "=".ToCharArray();
public static Dictionary<string, string> QueryDictionary(this Uri uri)
{
    return uri.ToString()
        .Split(QueryStringSeparator1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(a => a.Split(QueryStringSeparator2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(b => b.Split(QueryStringSeparator3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(c => c.Split(QueryStringSeparator4))
                .Where(c => c[0].Length > 0)
                .ToDictionary(c => Uri.UnescapeDataString(c[0]), c => c.Length > 1 ? Uri.UnescapeDataString(c[1]) : ""))
            .ElementAtOrDefault(1))// after ?
        .FirstOrDefault()// before #
        ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

Note: on a Windows Phone 7 device, `Uri.Query` is **unreliable** for an Uri like "mailto:a@example.com?subject=subject&body=body". That's why we use `Uri.ToString()` (itself better than `Uri.OriginalString`). If you only want to handle "(http|https)://" or you want to optimize for a Windows Phone 8 device, you can find an optimized solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/25167971/1033581.

If you want this `Uri.Query` optimization on a Windows Phone 8 device using a Windows Phone 7 app, you can check beforehand:

```
public static readonly bool IsVersion8 = Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(8, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone else has another way of doing it, I was able to accomplish the same thing manually:

```
// The url looked something like this http://www.mysite.com?param1=value&param2=value
var parameterValue = e.Uri.Query.Split('&')
            .Where(s => s.Split('=')[0] == "param2")
            .Select(s => s.Split('=')[1])
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't think this way is *bad*, I was just wondering if there was a built in method for this type of parsing because I know it existed in ASP.NET, .NET , etc.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired on the answer of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888883/is-there-a-simple-way-to-get-query-string-parameters-from-a-uri-in-windows-phone/15985000#15985000),

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ParseQueryString(Uri uri)
{
    var substring = uri.Query;
    if (substring.Length > 0)
         substring.Substring(1);

    var pairs = substring.Split('&'); 
    var output = new Dictionary<string, string>(pairs.Length);

    foreach (string piece in pairs)
    {
        var pair = piece.Split('=');
        output.Add(
            Uri.UnescapeDataString(pair[0]),
            Uri.UnescapeDataString(pair[1]));
    }

    return output;
}
```