# Is there a simple way to get query string parameters from a URI in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, uri, query-string, windows-phone

I'm currently working with a Custom URI Scheme to validate users using OAuth. In order to do this, I need to get the values of certain parameters from the query string.

Is there a simple way to get this information? Or is my only option to using REGEX or other string manipulation?

I have previously found references to things like ParseQueryString, but these are contained in libraries not available on Windows Phone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936266/how-to-break-apart-a-uri-in-wp7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of searching I landed on a simple approach. So long as query strings are kept fairly simple (as they are in OAuth) this method should work.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ParseQueryString( string uri ) {

    string substring = uri.Substring( ( ( uri.LastIndexOf('?') == -1 ) ? 0 : uri.LastIndexOf('?') + 1 ) );

    string[] pairs = substring.Split( '&' );

    Dictionary<string,string> output = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    foreach( string piece in pairs ){
        string[] pair = piece.Split( '=' );
        output.Add( pair[0], pair[1] );
    }

    return output;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/25164964/1033581:

- handling a *#* in the Uri
- handling possible missing value like *&name=* in the Uri
- not forgetting `Uri.UnescapeDataString`
- returning a `Dictionary` instead of a `IEnumerable` so one can find a desired parameter easily

For Windows Phone 7 device (or you only have a string, not an Uri, then just replace `uri.OriginalString` with your string),

```
static readonly char[] QueryStringSeparator1 = "#".ToCharArray();
static readonly char[] QueryStringSeparator2 = "?".ToCharArray();
static readonly char[] QueryStringSeparator3 = "&".ToCharArray();
static readonly char[] QueryStringSeparator4 = "=".ToCharArray();
public static Dictionary<string, string> QueryDictionary(this Uri uri)
{
    return uri.OriginalString
        .Split(QueryStringSeparator1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(a => a.Split(QueryStringSeparator2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(b => b.Split(QueryStringSeparator3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(c => c.Split(QueryStringSeparator4))
                .Where(c => c[0].Length > 0)
                .ToDictionary(c => Uri.UnescapeDataString(c[0]), c => c.Length > 1 ? Uri.UnescapeDataString(c[1]) : ""))
            .ElementAtOrDefault(1))// after ?
        .FirstOrDefault()// before #
        ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

Note: on a Windows Phone 7 device, `Uri.Query` is **unreliable** for an Uri like "mailto:a@example.com?subject=subject&body=body". That's why we use `Uri.OriginalString`.

For Windows Phone 8 device and you have an Uri, you can optimize this way,

```
static readonly char[] QueryStringSeparator1 = "#".ToCharArray();
static readonly char[] QueryStringSeparator3 = "&".ToCharArray();
static readonly char[] QueryStringSeparator4 = "=".ToCharArray();
public static Dictionary<string, string> QueryDictionary(this Uri uri)
{
    return uri.Query
        .Split(QueryStringSeparator1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(a => a.Substring(1)
            .Split(QueryStringSeparator3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(c => c.Split(QueryStringSeparator4))
            .Where(c => c[0].Length > 0)
            .ToDictionary(c => Uri.UnescapeDataString(c[0]), c => c.Length > 1 ? Uri.UnescapeDataString(c[1]) : ""))
        .FirstOrDefault()// before #
        ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

If you want to know if you are on a Windows Phone 8 device using a Windows Phone 7 app:

```
public static readonly bool IsVersion8 = Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(8, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone XNA games, access the startup parameters like this from your Game class ctor:

```
foreach (var lp in this.LaunchParameters) {
    Debug.WriteLine("  Key={0}, Value={1}", lp.Key, lp.Value);
}
```

In Silverlight/XAML apps, you would use e.InitParams from the Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) event handler.  An example of how to do that is here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2009/08/15/provide-startup-parameters-to-silverlight-with-initparams.aspx